# Data validation in google forms related to questions

Tags: google-forms

hiii, i am new here, I am preparing a google form, and wanted data validation details as below:

Question 1 - how many children with you
Ans (example)- 3
Question 2 - Son
Ans (example)- 1
Question 3 - Daughter
Ans (example)- 2

I want validation in last both answers, that Answer 2 & 3 must match with Answer 1

waiting for your fruitful responses...

Answer (score 0):

For validating check the official support google docs

check this below mentioned links for validation in google forms

reference: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, but my question is different, i already tried that but there is no solution for my question,